# GD Image resize doesn't work PHP

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

I've got the following piece of code:

```
$biggest = ($width > $height) ? $width : $height;
    $newWidth = 0;
    $newHeight = 0;

    if($biggest > $divSize){
        echo "BIGGEST<br />";
        $scale = $divSize/$biggest;
        $newWidth = floor($width * $scale);
        $newHeight = floor($height * $scale);
    } else if($biggest < $divSize){
        echo "DIVSIZE<br />";
        $scale = $biggest/$divSize;
        $newWidth = floor($width * $scale);
        $newHeight = floor($height * $scale);
    } 

    echo "SCALE: ".$scale."<br />";
    echo "BIGGEST: ".$biggest."<br />";
    echo "WIDTH: ".$width."<br />";
    echo "HEIGHT: ".$height."<br />";
    echo "NEWWIDTH: ".$newWidth."<br />";
    echo "NEWHEIGHT: ".$newHeight."<br />";

    $sourceImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fileName)); 
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);           
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    imagedestroy($sourceImage);
```

This piece of code works fine for some images but not for all of them.

I've got a div with the dimension of 64 by 64.

For some images they scale perfectly fine but for some images the height of the outputted image is also 64px what should by for example 32px.

I don't have a clue what's causing this problem.

If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

I figured it out myself.

I simplefied the code for scaling the thumbnail quite a bit:

```
$biggest = ($width > $height) ? $width : $height;
$newWidth = 0;
$newHeight = 0;
$scale = ($biggest >= $thumbSize) ? $thumbSize/$biggest : $biggest/$thumbSize;

$newWidth = floor($width * $scale);
$newHeight = floor($height * $scale);       

$sourceImage = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fileName)); 
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);           
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
imagedestroy($sourceImage);
```

Maybe someone can use this.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is good but sometimes your image should have a static size (this avoid to break design on some web pages).

In such a case, you can use this function. It resizes an image fit inside a defined width / height, and if the image has not the same proportions as the required thumbnail's, unused free space is set transparent.

```
function resizePreservingAspectRatio($img, $targetWidth, $targetHeight)
{
    $srcWidth = imagesx($img);
    $srcHeight = imagesy($img);

    // Determine new width / height preserving aspect ratio
    $srcRatio = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;
    $targetRatio = $targetWidth / $targetHeight;
    if (($srcWidth <= $targetWidth) && ($srcHeight <= $targetHeight))
    {
        $imgTargetWidth = $srcWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = $srcHeight;
    }
    else if ($targetRatio > $srcRatio)
    {
        $imgTargetWidth = (int) ($targetHeight * $srcRatio);
        $imgTargetHeight = $targetHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        $imgTargetWidth = $targetWidth;
        $imgTargetHeight = (int) ($targetWidth / $srcRatio);
    }

    // Creating new image with desired size
    $targetImg = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);

    // Add transparency if your reduced image does not fit with the new size
    $targetTransparent = imagecolorallocate($targetImg, 255, 0, 255);
    imagefill($targetImg, 0, 0, $targetTransparent);
    imagecolortransparent($targetImg, $targetTransparent);

    // Copies image, centered to the new one (if it does not fit to it)
    imagecopyresampled(
       $targetImg, $img, ($targetWidth - $imgTargetWidth) / 2, // centered
       ($targetHeight - $imgTargetHeight) / 2, // centered
       0, 0, $imgTargetWidth, $imgTargetHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight
    );

    return $targetImg;
}
```

Usage example :

```
$gd = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/image5.jpg");
$resized = resizePreservingAspectRatio($gd, 100, 100);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($resized);
```

This image :

[image]

Becomes :

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. What does your function do more then my function does?

My function creates a thumbnail that fits inside the given dimensions. And I center the thumb with css.

I think its a matter of taste whether you use GD or CSS to center the thumb. Now my images are smaller when they can be smaller.

Comment: Please let met now what's the benefit of your function?

Comment: It uses a fixed width and height. If you're displaying those image in a table, this avoid to have sometimes a large column, sometimes a high column : you always get the same size.